# AEM - Servlet resource cannot be found

Tags: servlets, sling, aem-6

I'm new to AEM and have been trying to connect to a servlet on an AEM project package which I installed on a new AEM instance.

It seems as if servlet cannot be found or the path cannot be found for the servlet and have double checked the mapping but am lost to what else I can look at. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Sling Mapping**

```
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
jcr:primaryType="sling:Mapping"
sling:internalRedirect="content/dam/test.$1.json"
sling:match="aem.test.com.4545/api/assets/v1/(.*)"/>
```

**Servlet Information**

```
`@Component(service = Servlet.class,
        property = {
                Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION + "=Get Job Folder Info API",
                "sling.servlet.methods=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_POST,
                "sling.servlet.resourceTypes=" + "sling/servlet/default",
                "sling.servlet.selectors=" + "jobFolderInfo",
                "sling.servlet.extensions=" + APIConstants.JSON_EXTENSION_TYPE
        })
public class JobFolderInfoServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {`
```

**Error log from request**

> 0 TIMER_START{Request Processing}
>
> 1 COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed microseconds>,<timer name>} <optional message>
>
> 6 LOG Method=POST, PathInfo=null
>
> 7 TIMER_START{handleSecurity}
>
> 1645 TIMER_END{1636,handleSecurity} authenticator org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.SlingAuthenticator@5f62558d returns true
>
> 1876 TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
>
> 3112 TIMER_END{1234,ResourceResolution} URI=/api/assets/v1/jobFolderInfo resolves to Resource=NonExistingResource, path=/apps/content/dam/test.jobFolderInfo.json
>
> 3119 LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/apps/content/dam/test.jobFolderInfo.json', selectorString='jobFolderInfo', extension='json', suffix='null'
>
> 3119 TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
>
> 3122 TIMER_START{resolveServlet(/apps/content/dam/test.jobFolderInfo.json)}
>
> 3853 TIMER_END{730,resolveServlet(/apps/content/dam/test.jobFolderInfo.json)} Using servlet com.test.assets.api.servlets.JobFolderInfoServlet
>
> 3856 TIMER_END{736,ServletResolution} URI=/api/assets/v1/jobFolderInfo handled by Servlet=com.test.assets.api.servlets.JobFolderInfoServlet
>
> 3860 LOG Applying Requestfilters
>
> 3864 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct then you are trying to connect to the servlet using the url like `localhost:4502/bin/your-servlet-path` from a browser. If that is the case then register the servlet by using path. In the above servlet code you have registered using resource type.

To register using path use `sling.servlet.paths=/bin/your-servlet-path`

[Here](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html) is a link that will help you understand registering servlet better.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to register a servlet on a resourceType rather than on a path to be able to restrict access to your servlet.

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/resourcetypes.html

```
SlingServlet(methods = {"GET"},
metatype = true,
resourceTypes = {"services/powerproxy"},
selectors = {"groups"})
public class HandleClaim extends org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet
```